# Convert a array into an associative array (Bash)

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, associative-array

I had my code converting my string into an array, but i end up noticing that i will need it to be associative with $9 as key and the rest of the string as value

```
stringy=$(ls -l | awk '{print$3,$6,$7,$8,$9}') 
declare -a myarray=()
```

There is the possibility of doing it using something similar to?

```
readarray -t myarray <<< "$stringy"
```

(yes parse ls is not exactly wise ;) )

Comment: I don't think there's anything that will do this automatically. Write a loop.

Comment: From bash manual: "_When assigning to an associative array, the subscript is required_". So Bamar is absolutely right: a loop is unavoidable.